# Get raw data sent by postman on php

Tags: php, postman

I'm sending some raw json data wirh postman to a php script

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1883K.png)

[Sent data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BRUA.png)

I try to show the request data on the script

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
```

But I get this response

array(0) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` array is for [form data requests](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

You need to read json from input:

```php
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```